Error in Splitting Educational Videos into Segments Using Python (ffmpeg issue)
I created a Python project to split long educational videos into smaller segments, each focused on a single question. The program uses OCR to detect text on video frames, identifies the word "Question," extracts the number following it, and splits the video whenever the number increases.
here is the video i am tring to split ((video))
Here’s an example of the program’s output:
Video loaded: 14071 frames at 60 FPS, duration: 234.52s  
Frame 480, Time 8.00s, Question: 6  
...  
Frame 12360, Time 206.00s, Question: 7  
Creating segment 1: 8.00s to 206.00s  
Error: module 'ffmpeg' has no attribute 'Error'

I’ve shared the full code in a GitHub repository for reference: Automated Video Scene Cutting.
What the Program Does

Input: A long educational video.
Processing:

Detects text in each frame using OCR.
Searches for the word "Question" followed by a number.
Monitors when the number increases to identify segment boundaries.


Output: Creates video segments corresponding to individual questions.

The Problem
The program detects the questions and timestamps correctly, but when it tries to create the segments, I encounter the following error:
Error: module 'ffmpeg' has no attribute 'Error'

What I’ve Tried

Verified the ffmpeg-python library is installed (pip show ffmpeg-python confirms the installation).
Ensured the ffmpeg binary is accessible from the command line.
Reviewed the library documentation to ensure the correct usage of ffmpeg.
Tested with different video files to rule out input-specific issues.

Environment Details

OS: Windows 11
Python Version: 3.9.13
Key Libraries: ffmpeg-python

If anyone has insights into resolving this issue or suggestions for alternative approaches to handle this use case, I’d greatly appreciate your help.
Thank you!

Please note that a valid question about an error in your code on SO must contain a [mre], not a link to complete code, and the complete error traceback. Anyway, module 'ffmpeg' has no attribute 'Error' means that you tried to use an ffmpg.Error, and that no such thing exists...

So check that you are actually using the module you think you are (no other file with the same name?) and that it is installed correctly (try to uninstall/reinstall), and make clear how you installed it.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
